# Import data from XML file stored in blob into azure SQL Server

Tags: xml, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I am new to azure and I tried to find a solution on internet but I am unable to resolve the problem of importing the data from XML file stored in data factory into azure SQL Server.

Do, I need to convert it first into CSV file and then load it into azure SQL Server, How shall i proceed with this task ?

Problem is that I cannot save the xml file firstly on my local system and then use SSIS for loading it into SQL Server.

Thanks in advance for your reply and help.

Comment: Hi, 

Where are you getting your XML file from? 

Is it saved in a blob container?

Comment: Please show us more useful messages as Watsyyy mentioned. Data Factory can not do well with XML file,  also can't  help you convert the xml file to csv file.

Comment: Hi, I have created a azure integration project(ssis) in visual studio which calls the XML file which is present in azure data blob.  When I am running the SSIS project on my system, it works well as i use azure storage connection manager to call the xml file from azure.  Problem occurs when I deploy the project in the ssisdb using catalogue and execute the project from data factory by using pipeline which calls the catalogue. It fails at : unable to execute the container (foreach) which calls the xml files from azure. Error message is : The remote server returned an error (403) Forbidden.